# Join 3 One to Many Tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, many-to-many

i have 2 tables that each one has a one-to-many relation to the table between and the table between has ids of 2 other tables

```
dbo.Posts          dbo.Posts_Categories          dbo.Categories
   -ID                -ID                           -ID
   -Title             -PostID                       -Name
                      -CategoryID
```

result i expect is :

```
Title = post1          Categories = web,mobile,desktop
Title = post2          Categories = app,game
...
```

i know how to query this in sql using Stuff function and For Xml Path but i have no idea how do i do this in entity framework!

any suggestion or book for how to do works in this way might help!

**Edit:** EF classes added:

```
    public class Post : ReportingBase {
        public Post() { }

        [Required, MaxLength(500)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(500)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(500)]
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Visit { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<Post_Category> Posts_Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post_AttachedFile> Posts_AttachedFiles { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Image")]
        public virtual int? ImageID { get; set; }
        public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post_Category {
        public Post_Category() { }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int PostID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category : EntityBase {
        public Category() { }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(150)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<Post_Category> Posts_Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

thank you in advance

**Edit :** According to @IvanStoev answer i did following :

```
    List<P> p = context.Posts.Select(post => new {
        Title = post.Title,
        Categories = post.Posts_Categories.Select(pc => pc.Category.Name).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

and created a class called P :

```
public class P {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

but it doesn't work correctly and the problem is how to return the result.

Comment: Well, in order to help with EF query we need EF models (classes, fluent configuration etc.) rather than db tables.

Comment: i added the entities @IvanStoev

Comment: You can remove all those empty constructors - does nothing but clouds your code. Also, it is suggested to use `ICollection<Type>` instead of `List<Type>` when defining your one to many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF it's even easier than in SQL thanks to the concept of so called  [navigation properties](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/). All you need to know is a basic LINQ query syntax and just follow them (navigate) to get the data needed. For instance:

```
var result = db.Posts
    .Select(post => new
    {
        Title = post.Title,
        Categories = post.Posts_Categories
            .Select(pc => pc.Category.Name)
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

The result is a list of anonymous type having `string` Title property and `List<string>` Categories property containing the related category names.

Comment: it seems going to work but i have no idea how to return it! i mean i don't know what is results type @IvanStoev

Comment: Just create a class - `public class SomeClass { public string Title { get; set; } public List<string> Categories { get; set; } }` and use `post => new SomeClass { ... }`. The result type will be `List<SomeClass>`. Ah, I saw your edit - you are almost there, forgot to add `P` after the `new` :)

Comment: This is bad code. You shouldn't be calling `.ToList()` twice like that - it will cause two separate queries, where as, if you used navigational properties with `.Include()` you could do it with on query. Furthermore, EF would properly index the foreign keys you're joining upon. Downvote sir

Comment: @KellenStuart This was for EF Core 2.x sir. Back then, inner `ToList()` call was required by EF Core to opt-in to apply optimization to actually avoid N + 1 queries. There was no "single-query" mode, it was introduced in 3.0. W/o it, they executed N + 1 queries, with it - just 2 or 3 (similar to 5.x "split query" mode :-) It's not my fault that EF Core team is changing concepts every release and break the existing code in one way or another.

Comment: @IvanStoev If that is the case, the question should be tagged with <= EF 2.*. There is no indication from question or answer that this is an old version. Furthermore, many people using EF 3+ will end up here (like myself).

Comment: @KellenStuart The post is from 02/2017. You can't expect people to mark posts at the time of writing what version is used (except if it is older), so it is assumed to be the current at that time. If you think someone will go and edit older posts, it's not serious, especially if you have thousands of answers. Anyway, I don't think this particular post needs adjustments - in fact 3.x single query mode is causing more performance issues, that's why 5.x returned back the split query mode, which is basically the 2.x behavior. What about the inner ToList(), it is not essential.

Comment: @KellenStuart With all my respect, you seem to not understand the difference between *loading related data* (`Include`) and projection (`Select`). Both use navigation properties for joins, and the number of executed SQL queries is one and the same and depends on the query mode, not the query. So, if you need  projection query involving multiple entity sources, this is the way to go - with or without inner `ToList()`. Cheers.

Comment: @IvanStoev Why would you not write that query as `db.Posts.Include(x => x.Categories).Select(x => new { Title = x.Title, Categories = x.Categories}).ToList();`. Again, I think it matters to include that this is EF 2.0. "The post is old" is not a valid excuse - sometimes answers change over time; Google still returns this as one of the first results depending on the phrasing.

Comment: @KellenStuart Because we want to just select category names, and not full category objects. This is just an example, but in real cases the related objects might have a lot of properties. This is basically the idea of having DTO/VM objects and populate them with the only data needed. The term is *projection query*, and in simple words, LINQ `Select`. EFC (ORM) queries are not just for retrieving full entities, this is what you seem to not understand. If you are interested only for `Include` functionality, it is well documented, not sure why you landed here.

Comment: @KellenStuart To finish this little conversation, just in case I've tested the sample query from the answer in 3.x and 5.x, and it works perfectly and produces a single SQL query as expected, so your initial claims are incorrect, thus the whole follow up  "discussion".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linqpad (software) to get familiarize with the Linq query it builds lambda expression for you by connecting to the database and provides output too to cross verify.

The below one is the lambda expression for joining the tables you have mentioned.

```
p - Post  
pc - post_categories
c - categories
```

Code:

```
Posts.Join(Post_Categories, p => p.ID, pc => pc.ID, ( p, pc) => new { p = p, pc = pc})
     .Join(Categories, pcc => pcc.pc.CategoryID, c => c.ID, ( pcc, c) => new { pcc = pcc, c = c})
     .Select(p.Title)
     .Select(c.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `.Include()` for *any* join in EF Core.

I've come up with this simple example: *one person* can have *many dogs*.

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; } // One Person can have many Dogs
}

public class Dogs
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Generate the migrations after creating the models. Not going over how to do that in this answer.

Here's how you use `.Include()` to join upon the two different tables:

```
public class PersonRepository : RepositoryBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> FetchPeopleWithManyDogs()
    {
        return DatabaseContext.Person
            .Include(x => x.Dogs)
            .Where(x => x.Dogs.Count() > 1).ToList();
    }
}
```